# Change binding IP address in jasmin, Or use two rails development environments

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-16.04, jasmine2.0

I kind of have two questions in one, I am trying to bind the IP address from jasmine rails rubygem to something other than localhost.

The reason being is that I develop using Ruby on rails, and 50% of the time I am on my laptop and the other 50% of the time I work from my PC. So I need to be able to access it from the browser using both machines.

I tried using X Forwarding on the Linux machines, but this is very sluggish and slowing down my work.

So my two questions are, for the Rails way
1: Should I be changing the jasmine bind IP to something else, if so, how?
2: Should I be running the development server on both machines separately, rather than just ftp uploading to the PC from the laptop?

Comment: to easily make a public url for localhost you can use localtunnel or ngrok. another option is to deploy to a hosting platform.

Comment: This seems like a very hackey method. @maxpleaner

Comment: what kind of non-hacky method are you comparing it to?

Comment: I would much rather change the address that jasmine listens on, is that impossible?

Comment: it's not that simple. Changing address (binding the host, which is something you can do in any server) is only part of making an application visible to the internet. ngrok or localtunnel do this for you simply. That's why they're not totally free (you have a limit on the number of ports you expose at once).

Comment: Yes I know it is not as simple as just changing the listening address. I administer several production servers, so I very aware of the steps that need to be done. However the first step is changing the listening address on jasmine, which is the only step I am having an issue with. I don't need to setup an entire ngrok server and client setup just to overcome such a tiny issue. That is quite overkill in my mind @maxpleaner

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding this to my nginx conf

```
server {
    server_name         example.com;
    root /home/user/rails/public;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Host 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
        proxy_no_cache     $http_pragma $http_authorization;
    }

}
```